# How to create and save new POJO object based on another one requested from Hibernate+Java

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

I do have a Java Web Application. It does use `hibernate` for creating, updating, saving the web form data to database. The task is to create a new record in the database within the same table based on previous record. So, what I have now:

The code:

```
    //Function which returns a record from database based on UUID

    @Override
public Marriage getMarriageUuId(String uuId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Marriage.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq( "uuId", uuId ));

    return (Marriage) criteria.uniqueResult();
}

//function which does save new record
@Override
public Integer addMarriage(Marriage marry) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Integer) session.save(marry);
}

//the action itself
    Marriage newVersion= caseRegisterService.getMarriageUuId(marriage4.getUuId()); 

                        newVersion.setVoided(false);
                        newVersion.setState("3.EDIT");
                        newVersion.setVersion(oldVersion.getVersion()+1);
                        newVersion.setUuId(newUuId);
   caseRegisterService.addMarriage( newVersion );
```

I do have `UUID` and based on this I get some record from the database and assign it to the corresponding object. It's not set as primary key. The primary key is just an auto increment in `postgresql`. The code works but it just keeps updating the current object with the new data. Instead I want to to create the new record in the database with new data, plus previous data. If I create it the very first time, when it doesn't  exist in the database, then it creates that object but after it just keeps updating it.

From what I understand the problem is in `primary key`. So, when I get back the object from the database it comes back with it's unique `primary key`, and as the result `hibernate` just updates it. So, how to `reset` that `primary key` for the new object? So, that `hibernate` will think it's new object. I also dont want to manually increase it, it's not the right way.

Comment: Why would you reset the primary key of an existing, already persistent object. Leave that one as it is. Just create a new one and save it: `Marriage newMarriage = new Marriage(); newMarriage.setVersion(alreadyExistingMarriage.getVersion() + 1); addMarriage(newMarriage);`.

Comment: I did created new one as you can see. Then I want to assign the old data to new one with some changes. In your example you don't take in to account the old data..

Comment: No, you didn't create a new one. You're getting an existing one from the database. There is no `new Marriage()` in your code. And yes, I did take into account the old data: `newMarriage.setVersion(alreadyExistingMarriage.getVersion() + 1);`. This takes the version of the existing marriage, increments it, and stores it in the version of the new marriage.

Comment: yes, it would mean I need to set over 100 properties manually which I dont want to... There are only 5 of them as you can see, which I re-set for the new version. the rest I want to be in this new version as it is in the old one. BTW this line `Marriage newVersion= caseRegisterService.getMarriageUuId(marriage4.getUuId()); ` creates new Marriage

Comment: No. It **gets** an **existing** marriage from the database. Your entity is a huge bag of properties, so you need to deal with it. Create a method copying properties from a Marriage to another. It's grunt, but simple work that you have to deal with. Doing it would have taken less time than asking this question.

Comment: This is exactly what I dont want to do. Because I dont want to change the existing one, I want to copy it over to new object and then save it, without copy/pasting 100 lines. But if there are no way of re-seting that PK for the new object then, what else I can do..

Comment: There is, but it's ugly as hell. You wanto to copy a marriage, so implement a method that copies a marriage. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: I thought there are a way to somehow make empty that PK for the newly created object, overall its on Java side untill it was not send to postgresql.. anyway, as you said I could already write all those setters, for the time I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when we have something like this:

```
// open session, transaction

 Marriage newVersion= caseRegisterService.getMarriageUuId(marriage4.getUuId()); 
 newVersion.setVoided(false);
 newVersion.setState("3.EDIT");

// close session, transaction
```

Hibernate will update `newVersion` (with old `uuId`) cause of a session flush, even if you didn't call `update()` method.

So what you can try to do:

```
Marriage newVersion= caseRegisterService.getMarriageUuId(marriage4.getUuId()); 

// detach entity from session
session.evict(newVersion);

newVersion.setVoided(false);
newVersion.setState("3.EDIT");
newVersion.setVersion(oldVersion.getVersion()+1);

// reset primary key
newVersion.setId(null);

caseRegisterService.addMarriage( newVersion );
```

You can use a bit simpler code to load entity:

```
session.get(Marriage.class, uuId);
```

Comment: I tried to assign `null` to PK for the new object. Then it will throw null pointer exception, so its not gonna work that way...

Comment: @Daler You can try to assign `newUuId`

Comment: as I said, I dont have problems with `uuId`. I need this only to get the data. There are another `integer` valued `primary key`, which is being put by the database itself. This is what I need to be new in the new object

Comment: @Daler Please, add entities. And describe why you got a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Daler Anyway, If you have an auto generated primary key, you should set it to `null`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It says integer value can't be setted as null. I tried to cast it, same result. And I've done all these things which u r suggesting before I even posted it.. I think the problem is deeper, but I solved this problem by creating a new object and manually setting everything else.. Thx for trying to help. If u r interested you can easily create a test app... its not just setting it to null.

Comment: @Daler Do you use `Integer` for a key not `int`?

Comment: It's `int`. `protected int id;` This is declaration in java class. And hibernate xml mapping file is `<id name="id" column="marriageid"> <generator class="native" /> </id>`

Comment: @Daler Please always use `Integer` for primary key.